# Why python string concatenation turns out to be most memory-light?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, centos, ram

I was digging through python memory management algorithms and underlying C code and tested how it works, getting an unexpected result.

**Base**:

Generate a 5.5 Gb string on a 6 Gb RAM CentOS virtual machine, using several methods. Generation is done through a dict in which it says how many times what symbols should appear, sorted (e.g. `{3: 5, 1: 3}` should give '11133333').

**Expectation**:

- `''.join()` should work because it uses memcpy() and maximum it would use is part of a string plus a next part of an iterable. Although it creates a buffer, `dict` objects appear to work well with swap. Granulation of the custom iterable would do a trade-off between speed and memory usage.
- `''.format()` actually deallocates memory so it should work faster and better.
- `s1+=s2` should be the most memory heavy as it would hold both strings in memory and create a buffer for the new one.

**Result**:

Everything fails with MemoryError, except:
- `''.join()` with minimal granulation
- ... concatenation.

`python -m dis pymemory.py` showed me "INPLACE_ADD" for the concatenation operation, which does not gel with the C code I've looked at.

**Code**:

The code is a bit stripped, obviously all methods should be ran separately.

```
b = {
    0: 590615000,
    1: 591234001,
    2: 590895000,
    3: 590010000,
    4: 591552000,
    5: 590375000,
    6: 589251000,
    7: 589903000,
    8: 590806000,
    9: 590939000
}

# literal format
a = '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(str(0)*b[0], str(1)*b[1], str(2)*b[2], str(3)*b[3], str(4)*b[4], str(5)*b[5], str(6)*b[6], str(7)*b[7], str(8)*b[8], str(9)*b[9])
del a


# format
# MEMORY ERROR
d = {}
for k in b:
    d['k'+str(k)] = str(k)*b[k]
a = ('{}'*d.keys().__len__()).format(*['{'+str(k)+'}' for k in sorted(d.keys())]).format(**d)
del a
del d

# join
# MEM ERROR
def i_am_iter(d):
    for k in d:
        yield str(k)*d[k]
    raise StopIteration
a = ''.join(i_am_iter(b))

# concat
# WORKS!
a = ''
for k in b:
    a += str(k)*b[k]
```

**Question**:

Is there an explanation for this? Why concatenation works? Why doesn't join or format? Is there an optimization I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Okay, so it turns out if there's just one reference to the object, there's a optimization of concat, which makes it inplace and much quicker than most everything (except join and format) and most memory-light (including join and format).
http://blog.mclemon.io/python-efficient-string-concatenation-in-python-2016-edition
https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.2/whatsnew/node12.html#SECTION0001210000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out if there's just one reference to the object, there's a optimization of concat, which makes it inplace and much quicker than most everything (except join and format) and most memory-light (including join and format).
http://blog.mclemon.io/python-efficient-string-concatenation-in-python-2016-edition
https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.2/whatsnew/node12.html#SECTION0001210000000000000000